# File Uploading in Sakai

Tags: sakai

I want to know if there is a 'right' way to make file uploads through custom tools.

I've seen the https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/File+Uploads+with+RSF guide and it seens ok, but It stops with the file in memory with no further info. I can built a random file upload code but I want to make it Sakai-friendly (Using ContentHosting and Resources service?)

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided for the first part is a good example of how to get the upload initially processed. Going through RequestFilter will get your files validated, but you can use whatever method you want to upload it.

For  the second part, I'd look at the [ContentHosting webservice](https://source.sakaiproject.org/svn/webservices/trunk/cxf/src/java/org/sakaiproject/webservices/ContentHosting.java) (createContentItem) for an example of how to add a file from a byte[] in memory after you've uploaded it.

These methods in [ContentHostingService](https://javadocs.nightly.sakaiproject.org/org/sakaiproject/content/api/ContentHostingService.html) also accept InputStream as a parameter as of 2.7 (KNL-325), so you don't have to store the entire file in memory and can stream it as you're uploading, which you should do if the files are of any reasonable size.